# AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'get' json from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Iam traying to get boolean value by key
if the value is `true` there is no issue but if the value == `false` i got error `AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` 
this problem i faced alot even when i get data from db

**main code**

```
    if model.check_login(request):
        ad = User.objects.get(UID=login_user_uid(request))
        per = {"perto": False}
        status = per['perto']
        print(f'sdf {type(status)}')
        print(f'sdf {status}')
        if per['perto'] is True:
            return render(request, "users/add_user.html", {})
        else:
            return reverse('home')
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

**output**

```
sdf <class 'bool'>
sdf False
Internal Server Error: /add_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workstation\amon_env\envo\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\workstation\amon_env\envo\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\workstation\amon_env\envo\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**Error img**

[image: error img]

Comment: You're using `reverse()` inconsistently.  The final line of your code has `return redirect(reverse('login'))`, but the third-to-last line has `return reverse('home')`.  In one case you're using `redirect()`, and in the other case you're not.

Comment: i fixed this problem but the main issue still not

Comment: What is the main issue?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the main issue that i got error when i try to get key value and check it with if statement 
without if statement i got true or false from the variable status 
whe i try to check the value of the variable status i get AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'get' if only status is false if the variable status value is true there is no error and the code run just fine

Comment: @Kmaangaty: as explained that is because your view returns a string, not a HTTP response, therefore you can not use `return reverse(..)` in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return the result of a `reverse` in a view, since that is a `str`, and a view should return a `HttpResponse`:

```
if model.check_login(request):
    ad = User.objects.get(UID=login_user_uid(request))
    per = {"perto": False}
    status = per['perto']
    print(f'sdf {type(status)}')
    print(f'sdf {status}')
    if per['perto']:
        return render(request, 'users/add_user.html', {})
    else:
        return redirect('home')
else:
    return redirect('login')
```